# Why is this code's execution speed so different?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In **Internet Explorer 7**, this code executes consistently in **47** ms:

```
function updateObjectValues() {    
    $('.objects').html(12345678); // ~500 DIVs
}
```

however, this code executes consistently in **157** ms:

```
function updateObjectValues() {
    $('.objects').html('12345678'); // ~500 DIVs
}
```

Passing a number is over 3x faster than a string. Why are these results so dramatically different? And, is there any way to help the performance of the string?

Comment: probably because strings have to be parsed for html content while numbers don't. Try running the same test with .text instead of .html and see if there is still a big difference.

Comment: I believe, its because jquery is parsing the string as html.

Comment: Have you tried with `text` instead of `html`? Would be interesting.

Comment: @Felix: we got the same idea there, i was editing my original comment while you wrote yours :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery source code (or even the unminified production version), you'll see that the `if (typeof value === "string" ...` branch of the code is *significantly* more complex than the final `else` version that will occur when you pass in a number.

Here's the 1.4.4 code for if the value is a string:

```
} else if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnocache.test( value ) &&
    (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value )) &&
    !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

    value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

    try {
        for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
            // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
            if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
                jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
                this[i].innerHTML = value;
            }
        }

    // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
    } catch(e) {
        this.empty().append( value );
    }
}
```

Here's what it does with a number:

```
} else {
    this.empty().append( value );
}
```

Clearly, the overhead of all those additional checks and function calls add up. I mean, even just in the `if` statement at the top, there are *three* regular expression tests, a map lookup, and a string being made lower case — and that's before we get into the body of the statement (if we do, perhaps one of the checks returns `false`), which involves a further regex (as part of a parameterized replace) and a loop...

Answer (score 3):

I just ran a test and it seemed to confirm my original notion:

`.text(string)` is as fast as `.html(number)` ergo there must be string parsing overhead in `.html(string)`

Whether this overhead is in ie7 or in jQuery is not clear to me.
Ie8 doesn't seem to have the same problem, which would suggest that the problem is not i jQuery, but then ie8 has a much faster js engine than ie7...

Answer (score 2):

Numbers can be stored binary, possibly in a single register. Strings have to be stored as, well, a string, in memory. So an optimizing interpreter or JIT-compiler will take advantage of the possible speed an integer provides.

Also, as Martin Jespersen points out, the html() function may handle strings differently than numbers, performing more work on it - if it is aware of the differences. Kudos to Martin there.

Comment: *"So an optimizing interpreter or JIT-compiler will take advantage..."* So, that lets out IE7, then, with its famously rubbish JavaScript interpreter. ;-)

Comment: Indeed :). But recently, browser makers were competing about who's got the fastest JS engine, so right now the newer browsers will implement such or similar methods of increasing speed.

Answer (score 1):

As T.J. Crowder points out, a look at [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js) reveals that the code path is quite different for a string; ironically, the associated comment suggests that this is in an attempt to exploit a "shortcut":

```
html: function( value ) {
        if ( value === undefined ) {
            return this[0] && this[0].nodeType === 1 ?
                this[0].innerHTML.replace(rinlinejQuery, "") :
                null;

        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        } else if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnocache.test( value ) &&
            (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value )) &&
            !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

            value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

            try {
                for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                    if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
                        jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
                        this[i].innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }

            // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
            } catch(e) {
                this.empty().append( value );
            }

        } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
            this.each(function(i){
                var self = jQuery( this );

                self.html( value.call(this, i, self.html()) );
            });

        } else {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }

        return this;
    },
```